# What was really new about the message of Mohammed?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Mohammed had a message given to him by the Angel Gabriel. But I cann't find the a real new core of this message on the internet. So who can tell me what his core message was and was it really new or just updating the moral?

Comment: [Abrahamic religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahamic_religions) are not new to people. He just reminded that people still belong to Abrahamic religions and should worship the [One God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou_shalt_have_no_other_gods_before_me) and continue the [tradition](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8126/9123). His core message is [this](http://quran.com/112)

Answer (score 1):

The message answers some of the fundamental questions about life. [Wahiduddin Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahiduddin_Khan) has aptly put:

> Every book has its objective and the objective of the Quran is to make
>   man aware of the Creation plan of God. That is, to tell man why God
>   created this world; what the purpose is of settling man on earth; what
>   is required from man in his pre-death life span, and what he is going
>   to confront after death. [The Quran and the Creation Plan of God](http://www.cpsglobal.org/content/quran-and-creation-plan-god)

The purpose in mentioned in [Chapter 67](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/67:2)

> He created death and life so that He might test you, and find out
>   which of you is best in conduct. [67:2](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/67:2)

The requirements to succeed in the test are mentioned in the [Chapter 103](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/103:1).

> I swear by the passage of time, that man is surely in a state of
>   loss, except for those who believe and do good deeds and exhort
>   one another to hold fast to the Truth, and who exhort one another to
>   stead-fastness. [103:1-3](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/103:1)

The outcome of this trial is mentioned many times in the Quran.

> Give the good news to those who believe and do good works, that they
>   will have Gardens through which rivers flow [2:25](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/2:25)

The is the core message and this message has always been the same.

Answer (score -1):

Any prophet came to correct and make people remember that there is one God and to make the all people believe in Allah
Islam complete the other religions so no many different between Islam and other religions
For more information you can find it in azhar website just ask them and they will tell you more [azhar sharif][١]

http://www.azhar.eg/en/fatwa